# Iterators and Const iterators in C++?

Tags: c++, class, generics, methods, iterator

Let's suppose I have two classes, the first:

```
class IntMatrix::iterator {
private:
    const IntMatrix *int_matrix;
    int index;

    iterator(const IntMatrix *int_matrix, int index);

    friend class IntMatrix;

public:
    int &operator*() const;

    iterator &operator++();

    iterator operator++(int);

    bool operator==(const iterator &it) const;

    bool operator!=(const iterator &it) const;

    iterator(const iterator &) = default;

    iterator &operator=(const iterator &) = default;

    ~iterator() = default;
};
```

and the second is:

```
class IntMatrix::const_iterator {
private:
    const IntMatrix *int_matrix;
    int index;

    const_iterator(const IntMatrix *int_matrix, int index);

    friend class IntMatrix;

public:
    const int &operator*() const;

    const_iterator &operator++();

    const_iterator operator++(int);

    bool operator==(const const_iterator &it) const;

    bool operator!=(const const_iterator &it) const;

    const_iterator(const const_iterator &) = default;

    const_iterator &operator=(const const_iterator &) = default;

    ~const_iterator() = default;
};
```

How may I prevent code duplication here, since the implementation is 99% the same?
How about **generics** may it help here or **inheritance**?

An example of how they are implemented:

```
int &IntMatrix::iterator::operator*() const {
    return int_matrix->data[index];
}

const int &IntMatrix::const_iterator::operator*() const {
    return int_matrix->data[index];
}
```

Plus, I want In main to allow something like:

```
IntMatrix::iterator it;
```

---

**Update:
I'm trying to implement the given solution on a Generic class called Matrix in the following way: (Note the code shown is all written as public in my class)**

```
template<typename T>
class iterator_impl;

template<typename T>
iterator_impl<T> begin(){
    return iterator(this, 0);
}

template<typename T>
iterator_impl<T> end(){
    return iterator(this, size());
}

template<typename T>
iterator_impl<const T> begin() const
{
    return const_iterator(this, 0);
}

template<typename T>
iterator_impl<const T> end() const
{
    return const_iterator(this, size());
}

template<typename T>
class iterator_impl{
private:
    const Matrix<T> *matrix;
    int index;
    friend class Matrix<T>;

public:
    iterator_impl(const iterator_impl &) = default;

    iterator_impl &operator=(const iterator_impl &) = default;

    ~iterator_impl() = default;

    iterator_impl(const Matrix<T> *int_matrix, int index)
            : matrix(int_matrix), index(index) {}

    iterator_impl &operator++()
    {
        ++index;
        return *this;
    }

    iterator_impl operator++(int)
    {
        iterator_impl result = *this;
        ++*this;
        return result;
    }

    bool operator==(const iterator_impl &it) const
    {
        return index == it.index;
    }

    bool operator!=(const iterator_impl &it) const
    {
        return !(*this == it);
    }

    T &operator*() const {
        if (index < 0 || index > matrix->size() - 1) {
            throw Matrix<T>::AccessIllegalElement();
        }
        return matrix->data[index];
    }
};
template<typename T>
using iterator = iterator_impl<T>;

template<typename T>
using const_iterator = iterator_impl<const T>;
```

and I'm getting some errors like:

> invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
>           return iterator(this, 0);

Comment: @TedLyngmo could you change it to remove IMT, It made things really complicated on my side

Comment: the iterator code in my Matrix<T> class got totally broken and I didn't have a backup

Comment: I'm not sure I can remove `IMT` since your iterator is either pointing at a `const IntMatrix` or a non-`const` `IntMatrix`. I now changed it so `IMT` is deduced automatically instead.

Comment: writing you code as is gives me: non-member function cannot have 'const' qualifier when writing this:     const_iterator begin() const;

Comment: your code works for intMatrix not for Matrix<T>

Comment: I added a `Matrix<T>` example too.

Comment: Your previous edit made my answer very hard to understand for anyone else that searches for help on this topic Don't destroy your own question like that. I've rolled it back to the previous version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make the implementation into a class template and then to make aliases for the `const` and non-`const` instantiations.

> Plus, I want In main to allow something like:
>   `IntMatrix::iterator it;`

You then need to add a default constructor.

Example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

// in the .hpp file:
class IntMatrix {
private:
    int data[10];     // just an example
    size_t size = 10; // just an example

    template<typename T>
    class iterator_impl;

public:
    // two typedefs using the template:
    using iterator = iterator_impl<int>;
    using const_iterator = iterator_impl<const int>;

    const_iterator cbegin() const;
    const_iterator cend() const;
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
};

// still in the .hpp file:
template<typename T>
class IntMatrix::iterator_impl {
public:
    using matrix_type =
        std::conditional_t<
            std::is_const_v<T>,
            const IntMatrix,
            IntMatrix
        >;

private:
    matrix_type* int_matrix;
    size_t index;

    friend IntMatrix;

    iterator_impl(matrix_type* im, size_t idx) :
        int_matrix(im), index(idx)
    {}

public:
    iterator_impl() = default;                          // default constructor
    //iterator_impl(const iterator_impl&) = default;             // not needed
    //iterator_impl &operator=(const iterator_impl &) = default; // not needed
    //~iterator_impl() = default;                                // not needed

    iterator_impl &operator++() {
        ++index;
        return *this;
    }
    iterator_impl operator++(int) {
        iterator_impl old(*this);
        ++index;
        return old;
    }
    bool operator!=(const iterator_impl &it) const {
        return index != it.index || int_matrix != it.int_matrix;
    }
    bool operator==(const iterator_impl &it) const {
        return !(*this != it);
    }

    T& operator*() const {
        return int_matrix->data[index];
    }
};

// in the .cpp file:
IntMatrix::const_iterator IntMatrix::cbegin() const { return {this, 0}; }
IntMatrix::const_iterator IntMatrix::cend() const { return {this, size}; }
IntMatrix::const_iterator IntMatrix::begin() const { return cbegin(); }
IntMatrix::const_iterator IntMatrix::end() const { return cend(); }
IntMatrix::iterator IntMatrix::begin() { return {this, 0}; }
IntMatrix::iterator IntMatrix::end() { return {this, size}; }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KEsPyJ)

---

Edit: If `Matrix` is a class template itself, you need to change the iterator slightly.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

// in the .hpp file:
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    T data[10];       // just an example
    size_t size = 10; // just an example

    template<typename I>
    class iterator_impl;

public:
    // two typedefs using the template:
    using iterator = iterator_impl<T>;
    using const_iterator = iterator_impl<const T>;

    auto cbegin() const;
    auto cend() const;
    auto begin() const;
    auto end() const;
    auto begin();
    auto end();
};

// still in the .hpp file:
template<typename T>
template<typename I>
class Matrix<T>::iterator_impl {
public:
    using value_type = std::remove_const_t<I>;

    using matrix_type =
        std::conditional_t<
            std::is_const_v<I>,
            const Matrix<value_type>,
            Matrix<value_type>
        >;

private:
    matrix_type* matrix;
    size_t index;

    friend Matrix;

    iterator_impl(matrix_type* im, size_t idx) :
        matrix(im), index(idx)
    {}

public:
    iterator_impl() = default;                          // default constructor

    iterator_impl& operator++() {
        ++index;
        return *this;
    }
    iterator_impl operator++(int) {
        iterator_impl old(*this);
        ++index;
        return old;
    }
    bool operator!=(const iterator_impl &it) const {
        return index != it.index || matrix != it.matrix;
    }
    bool operator==(const iterator_impl &it) const {
        return !(*this != it);
    }

    I& operator*() const {
        return matrix->data[index];
    }
};

// still in the .hpp file
template<typename T> auto Matrix<T>::cbegin() const { return const_iterator{this, 0}; }
template<typename T> auto Matrix<T>::cend() const { return const_iterator{this, size}; }
template<typename T> auto Matrix<T>::begin() const { return cbegin(); }
template<typename T> auto Matrix<T>::end() const { return cend(); }
template<typename T> auto Matrix<T>::begin() { return iterator{this, 0}; }
template<typename T> auto Matrix<T>::end() { return iterator{this, size}; }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/XkgN6V)

Comment: wouldn't inheritance be best option here?

Comment: @smith Some people like inheritance and casting better for this kind of thing, but I personally don't. I can't say that one is better than the other.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, should I change anything in .h file or all the changes in .cpp file?

Comment: You can do the implementation of the class template functions in the cpp file if you wish, but you must then instantiate both versions explicitly - which isn't a problem when you use it for `int` and `const int` only. It will however be harder if you make your Matrix class into a template too. I would stick to having the complete `iterator_impl` implementation in the header file.

Comment: when I try to access data I get error that it's private, plus my professor said never to use using in .h files and he will reduce points, how to prevent this?

Comment: If you want the `iterator_impl<>` classes to have direct access to `data` you can make them `friend`. "_my professor said never to use using in .h files_" - I think your prof was talking about `using namespace ...;` which is bad if done into the global namespace - especially in header files. The `using` I'm doing above is making two aliases/`typedef`s and is perfectly safe.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a better name for the class :-) it sound a little bit strange to call it implementation

Comment: @smith You are welcome. Naming is hard. I usually call my template `iterator_impl` and have a hard time figuring out a better name :-)

Comment: @smith Ok, I added some more details to the answer.

Comment: what is IMT things got really complicated, I have posted a clear new question with all of what I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62375238/implementing-iterator-debugging-failed

Comment: @smith `IMT` is just `IntMatrix` or `const IntMatrix` depending on if it's the `iterator` or `const_iterator`, but I'll take a look at the other question later tonight.

Comment: @smith Check out the demo-link I added at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215952/discussion-between-ted-lyngmo-and-smith).

Comment: Sure, the problem got partially solved on regular class, please see my updates (in the bottom of my edited question) sorry for taking a lot of your time